# ASP.NET MVC - Refresh Auth Cookie on Anonymous Ajax Requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, owin

I'm trying to refresh a session after an ajax request to a controller that has the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute. For some reasons removing this attribute is not a possibility right now. The authentication is being made via OWIN *(Microsoft.Owin v4.1.0)*.

Here is how the authentication is made:

```
public class Startup_Auth
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        try
        {
            MyAuthenticationProvider provider = new MyAuthenticationProvider() { OnValidateIdentity = MyValidation };
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType("ExternalCookie");
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "ExternalCookie",
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                CookieName = "MyCookie",
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
                LoginPath = new PathString(PATH),
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(EXPIRATION),
                Provider = provider,
                TicketDataFormat = new MyTicketDataFormat()
            });
        }
        ...
    }

    private static Task MyValidation(CookieValidateIdentityContext context)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I have also tried by the controller's `OnActionExecuting`:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // can't access cookies here
    }
}
```

Any suggestions will be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a claims identity and call SignIn on the AuthenticationManager (SignInManager.SignInAsync) this way, the Claims are updated:

```
// Get User and a claims-based identity
ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
var Identity = new ClaimsIdentity(User.Identity);

// Remove existing claim and replace with a new value
await UserManager.RemoveClaimAsync(user.Id, Identity.FindFirst("AccountNo"));
await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("AccountNo", value));

// Re-Signin User to reflect the change in the Identity cookie
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

// [optional] remove claims from claims table dbo.AspNetUserClaims, if not needed
var userClaims = UserManager.GetClaims(user.Id);
if (userClaims.Any())
{
    foreach (var item in userClaims)
    {
        UserManager.RemoveClaim(user.Id, item);
    }
}
```